# Maximum values from a SQL Query

Tags: sql

I thought I had this cracked but it returns to many results. I will try and explain this better.

I have a table which holds delivery type(I.e. One Man Delivery, Two Man Delivery) information for products. Delivery costs will vary between products and each product can have multiple delivery types.

If a user adds two products to the cart, I need to display the most expensive delivery options from either of the products in the cart.

EG.

```
Product 1
id=2  
Delivery Type=One Man delivery  
Cost=**£30**
id=2  
Delivery Type=Two Man delivery  
Cost=£40  

Product 2
id=4  
Delivery Type=One Man delivery  
Cost=£40
id=4  
Delivery Type=Two Man delivery  
Cost=**£60** 

The results should be;

id=4  
Delivery Type=Two Man delivery  
Cost=**£60** 
id=2  
Delivery Type=One Man delivery  
Cost=**£30**
```

I need to also get the `uid` of the table. This stops the query from getting the right results. It will return all delivery types. If i remove the `uid` it displays the correct results. It seems to stop the group by.

```
<cfquery name="getDeliveryType" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT  txt_pdelopt_type, MAX(mon_pdelopt_actcost) AS myCost, uid_pdelopt
    FROM    dbo.tbl_product_deliveryopt 
    WHERE   bit_pdelopt_active=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes"> 
    AND     uid_pdelopt_prodid IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="4,5" list="yes">) 
    GROUP BY txt_pdelopt_type, uid_pdelopt
    ORDER BY myCost DESC
</cfquery>
```

What's the best way to approach this? Any help is appreciated.

> I think I sold myself a dummy! If I have two products with the same delivery options and costs I get all the delivery types returned as none of the costs are larger than each over?

It's late here at the moment, and I'm confusing myself let alone you guys trying to help!

So I'm not sure what I am trying to do is going to achieve what I need!

Lets try and start from the beginning;

Table: `tbl_product_deliveryopt`
UID: `uid_pdelopt`
Product Id: `uid_pdelopt_prodid`
Delivery Type:  `txt_pdelopt_type`
Cost: `mon_pdelopt_actcost`

This table contains delivery types related to the product. The product uid is `uid_products`.

Each product can have several delivery types, such as One Man Delivery, Two Man Delivery.

Each delivery type may have different costs depending on the size of the product.

If two products are added to the cart, I first need to find the dearest delivery cost and then display the highest cost we have found along with the other options which share the `uid_pdelopt_prodid` of the highest cost we found.

EG:

Product 1
Del Type: One Man
Cost: £20
ProdID: 3

Product 1
Del Type: Two Man
Cost: £40
ProdID: 3

Product 2
Del Type: One Man
Cost: £10
ProdID: 4

Product 2
Del Type: Two Man
Cost: £20
ProdID: 4

Because product 1 has the highest delivery charge I need to display product 1's delivery charges.

However two products may have the same delivery charge, in this case I still only need to display one set of options, but they must have the same `uid_pdelopt_prodid`.

In other words i can not display a mixture of the options they need to be related by the `uid_pdelopt_prodid`.

Does this it explain it any better?

Comment: the requirement isn't clear to me at all - can you simplify your example? e.g. sample data and desired outputs. Also, is coldfusion relevant to the problem?

Comment: Could you post the table ddl? The columns names are bit cryptic. It is not clear which ids relate to the hard coded list: `4,5`. Also, it is always good to include your database type with sql questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving the uid breaks the `GROUP BY` because it is unique and if you group by a unique field, every row falls into it's own group.

I'm not 100% sure about your table structure and what fields mean etc, but what about something like this?

```
SELECT pdo.uid_pdelopt, pdo.txt_pdelopt_type, pdo.mon_pdelopt_actcost
FROM   dbo.tbl_product_deliveryopt pdo
       INNER JOIN (
                   SELECT  txt_pdelopt_type
                           , uid_pdelopt_prodid
                           , MAX(mon_pdelopt_actcost) AS max_cost
                   FROM    dbo.tbl_product_deliveryopt 
                   WHERE   bit_pdelopt_active = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes"> 
                   AND     uid_pdelopt_prodid IN 
                           (
                              <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.uid_pdelopt_prodid#" list="yes">
                           ) 
                   GROUP BY txt_pdelopt_type, uid_pdelopt_prodid 
          ) 
          pdo_max ON (pdo_max.txt_pdelopt_type = pdo.txt_pdelopt_type 
                  AND pdo_max.max_cost = pdo.mon_pdelopt_actcost 
                  AND pdo_max.uid_pdelopt_prodid = pdo.uid_pdelopt_prodid)

WHERE   pdo.bit_pdelopt_active = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes"> 
AND     pdo.uid_pdelopt_prodid IN 
            (
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.uid_pdelopt_prodid#" list="yes">
            )

ORDER BY pdo.mon_pdelopt_actcost DESC
```

The inline view (inner query) returns the highest cost per `uid_pdelopt_prodid` and `txt_pdelopt_type`. Then you join that back to the original table to filter down to only rows that have that max cost. Allowing you to pull back the `uid_pdelopt` as well.

Comment: Hi Ninesided, thanks for this it is now working correctly. Just a quick question if I needed to make sure the delivery types were related by the product id ie, only show the delivery types which are dearest and both share `uid_pdelopt_prodid` would that be possible? Once again thanks ever so much for your help!!

Comment: @JasonCongerton - I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand (again!) can you add an **EDIT** block to the original question with an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Leigh - what did you do to my query?! I can hardly read it now! Thanks for correcting my typo's though :-)

Comment: @ninesided - The old one was really "sqooshed" together and difficult to read. So I added whitespace to improve readability. Granted with big queries, there is only so much you can do ;-) But feel free to roll it back if you do not like it :)

Comment: @Leigh - nah, just winding you up :D

Comment: @ninesided - :P Now I am going to roll it back just to mess with you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by and sum the cost to get the total cost per situation. Then order by the sum. The first row will be the largest.

Another option is to use a 'having clause' the allows you to do conditions on aggregates like sum.

You would say 
...
Group by x
Having sum(y) = max(y)